# Rails Active Record Associations: fetch data from multiple table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have tables in db as following migration script:

```
class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :physicians do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :patients do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :appointments do |t|
      t.belongs_to :physician, index: true
      t.belongs_to :patient, index: true
      t.datetime :appointment_date
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And the model class looks like:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

I'm able to pick all patients data of specific physician using:

```
patients = Physician.find(123).patients
```

The problem is, I need appointment_date, which is stored in appointment table, along with patient details. Somehow I'm not able to figure out how to fetch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relation looks completely right so querying should be quite easy or are you having some problems?

If you need appointment_date i would probably query Appointments of Physician instead:

```
Physician.find_by(id: 123).appointments.each do |x|
  print "Date: #{x.appointment_date}\n"
  print "Patient: #{x.patient.name}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `join` `Patient` and `Appointment` models to get the required data easily:

```
Patient.joins(:appointments).where(. . . ).select('appointments.appointment_date')
```

You can put the required condition in the `where` clause and add more attributes from the `patients` and `appointments` tables in the select clause that you want to select.

See [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for more information on this.

#### Update

I misunderstood your question initially. Th easiet way to get what you want is pointed by `midN` in his answer.